# Increase performance of Remote Scan

Tags: sql-server, performance, statistics

I have a SQL Server query looking something like this:

```
  UPDATE T1
  SET PersonID  = 'L0299'
  FROM [RemoteIP].MyDB1.dbo.Persons P 
       INNER JOIN Inserted I ON P.ID = I.ID
       INNER JOIN [RemoteIP].MyDB1.dbo.Departments D ON D.DepID = I.DepID
  WHERE EventTime >= '2014-08-13'
```

The basic idea is that when I update a record in a local table, it should update records in a remote table.
Problem is, this query is slow.  Takes about 2 min 20s from SSMS.

Persons table have 300K records and Departments have 300 records.

Execution plan looks like this:
[image]

So, the problem is the Remote Scan on table Persons.
The pop up on Remote Scan looks like this:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to improve performance?
I have statistics turned on with indexes on all fields that are used in the joins.

Comment: Which table does eventtime come from?

Comment: In addition - what versions of sql server are involved? In <= 2012 SP1 IIRC seeing stats on the remote side required owner or sysadmin (generically). Also, the most offending part of that is the remote scan with the huge fat line at the end and we only have estimates but not actuals. The filter was not pushed to the remote side, have you tried using openquery() to see if that pushes the filter? Have you checked for locking/blocking issues as well?

Comment: Kevin: EventTime comes from the big table Persons.

Comment: Sean: Server is running SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition SP2.  There are no locks, but I have not checked the openquery().  Will look into that.